# Whats the difference between method argument with and without underscore _ in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I try to find out the purpose of underscore in method argument but not find any reason. Like there is a method

```
def eligible(user)
end
```

and same method but with an underscore in argument

```
def eligible(_user)
end
```

whats the difference between them

Comment: In this context, there is no difference. Names of *block variables* commonly begin with an underscore (or are simply an underscore) when the variable is not used in the block calculations. This is mainly to bring that fact to the attention of readers.  Similarly, a variable beginning with an underscore may appears on the left of an equals sign to indicate it is consuming  an object that will not be used later. For example, `a, _, b` = [1, 2, 3]`, in which case `_ #=> 2` will not be referenced in the code that follows...

Comment: ...Names of method arguments, as here, are different. If a variable is not used by a method, regardless of whether its name begins with an underscore, it has no business being an argument of that method. Including it as an argument only causes confusion. Nonetheless, some coders name variables with a leading underscore for reasons of their own and I have no problem with that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sometimes it's to conform to an existing expectation, or it's for future use. Tools like Visual Studio Code and Rubocop can chew you out for unused variables, but `_` provides an assurance you understand and the warnings are suppressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just code convention to underscore a variable if you're not gonna use it later on. It has no meaning otherwise.

> Use _ for unused variables.

from ... https://clearwater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Clearwater_Ruby_Coding_Guidelines.html#naming

Also see this for further reading on style preferences.
https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 2):

`_` has some meaning as part of the ruby syntax.

Ruby will suppress warnings of unused variables that start with `_`:

```rb
# underscore.rb

def unused_variables_check
  _nowarn = "not used, but warning is suppressed"
  notused = "not used"
  used    = "i need it 100%"
  used
end

# $ ruby -w underscore.rb
# underscore.rb:3: warning: assigned but unused variable - notused
```

Ruby does not complain about unused arguments:

```
def unused_arguments_check(a, b)
  p a
end
unused_arguments_check("yay", "nup")

# $ ruby -w underscore.rb
# "yay"
```

Duplicate argument names is an error:

```
def dup_arguments_check(a, a) end

# $ ruby -w underscore.rb
# underscore.rb:14: duplicated argument name
# def dup_arguments_check(a, a) end
```

Unless those names start with an underscore. This is a ruby syntax feature, not just a style guide. It is used on occasion to ignore arguments:

```
def dup_arguments_with_underscore_check(_a, _a, _, _)
  p _a # don't use it after "ignoring". but, i thought, it would be the last `_a`
  p _
end
dup_arguments_with_underscore_check(:x, :lost_i, :y, :n_limbo)

# $ ruby -w underscore.rb
# :x
# :y
```

---

`_` has some semantic meaning as part of a style guide. Most common meaning is "this is unused variable/argument".

`rubocop` is a style checker/formatter. It will complain about everything, including unused arguments.

```sh
$ rubocop -l
Inspecting 1 file
W

Offenses:

underscore.rb:3:3: W: Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - notused.
  notused = "not used"
  ^^^^^^^
underscore.rb:9:31: W: [Correctable] Lint/UnusedMethodArgument: Unused method argument - b. If it's necessary, use _ or _b as an argument name to indicate that it won't be used.
def unused_arguments_check(a, b)
                              ^
underscore.rb:16:45: W: Lint/UnderscorePrefixedVariableName: Do not use prefix _ for a variable that is used.
def dup_arguments_with_underscore_check(_a, _a, _, _)
                                            ^^
underscore.rb:16:52: W: Lint/UnderscorePrefixedVariableName: Do not use prefix _ for a variable that is used.
def dup_arguments_with_underscore_check(_a, _a, _, _)
                                                   ^
#                                               ^
#  Hey, rubocop, I'm using the first `_` -------'
```

By using `_` to match a common style, everyone looking at your code, including future self, will have a bit of extra information.

---

Ruby convention: *https://rubystyle.guide/#underscore-unused-vars*

Rubocop convention: *https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_lint.html#lintunusedmethodargument*